# How to print a defined string macro in C?

Tags: c, string, macros, printf, c-preprocessor

I apologize in advance if this has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find anything on SO which relates *specifically* to this.

Basically, let's say I have a simple macro:

`#define STR "somestring"`

When I do a `printf` or `puts` on that macro, I get a

```
error: expected ')' before ';' token
```

It's literally as simple as:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    puts( STR ); //error

    return 0;
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: It works fine: http://ideone.com/jN8nQ.  The problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Could it be you have `#define STR "somestring";` ?

Comment: (I'm betting on a `;` after that define)

Comment: @Mat you deserve a lollipop :)

And, my most sincerest apologies folks.

Comment: This is what happens when you don't post the *exact* code that you are actually using.

Comment: @GregHewgill: What, you get a correct answer 5 minutes after posting the question?  That's *usually* not what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely that `STR` is redefined at some point in your program.  The following code compiles just fine.

```
#define STR "something"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    puts(STR);
    return 0;
}
```

As an experiment try picking a different name, say `STR_TEST` and see if that works.  If so then you know the macro is defined elsewhere

Another possible source of error is that the `#define` line ends in a `;` (it shouldn't)

Comment: It did end with a `;`. Check the question post's comments.